# Access Wont Sort Currency by Total Value - SQL - Rank

Tags: sql, ms-access, format, currency, ranking

This might be a simple question, but surprisingly I haven't found anything that fits here. I've made a query in which I format a number as currency. 
Specifically:

```
Format((Sum([CombineTables].[Total Extended Price])),'Currency')
```

Now when I try to sort on Access it does something like this:

```
$9,994,340.95
$9,200.50
$9.75
$8,000,0000.00
$4,000
$1,000,000,000.00
```

I would like to rank these through SQL, and sorting i think would be the easiest way to do this. Do you know how to correct this problems, the outputs still need to be in the currency format.

Thank you in advance

Comment: looks to me like it's treating/sorting it as a string, you should add another 'column' for `Sum([CombineTables].[Total Extended Price])` and sort on that. in the query designer you can check/uncheck a box for displaying it in the output iirc

Comment: Good workaround, thank you... I'd like to mark your comment as the answer for your credit, and to avoid unneccesary reads - But unable. Will try again in awhile. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me like it's treating/sorting it as a string, you should add another 'column' for `Sum([CombineTables].[Total Extended Price])` and sort on that. in the query designer you can check/uncheck a box for displaying it in the output iirc

Answer (score 1):

Well, one option is to `order by` the original value:

```
order by Sum([CombineTables].[Total Extended Price])
```

If you can't do that for some reason *and* everything has the same format, use this trick:

```
order by len(TotalExtendedPrice), TotalExtendedPrice
```

(or whatever the column is).

You can handle decimals with this trick:

```
order by len(TotalExtendedPrice) - iif(TotalExtendedPrice like '*.*',  3, 0),
         TotalExtendedPrice
```

Comment: That's a cool trick, but I don't think it will work in his case because from the sample date sometimes he includes decimals and sometimes not, so your sort would rank $1,000.00 as larger than $9,999